# Name of different representation of Latitude and Longitude

Tags: terminology

There are two (at least) kinds of representation of Latitude and Longitude:

- when a value is represented in degrees, arc minutes and arc seconds (for example 12° 34' 56.78");
- when a value is represented as integer and fractional parts of degrees (for example 12.582439°).

My question: how those kinds of representation are called?

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal

Comment: "Sexagesimal degrees" (or Degree-Minutes-Seconds (DMS)) vs "Decimal Degrees". See Wikipedia's ["Decimal degrees" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).

Comment: @Blue, thank you! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sexagesimal degrees" (or Degree-Minutes-Seconds (DMS)) vs "Decimal Degrees" (DD).

See Wikipedia's ["Decimal degrees" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).